# Вылетает с ошибкой что делать?

Tags: c#

````
```C#

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
/// <summary>
/// Description of Form1.
/// </summary>
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void PictureBox1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void graphics()
    {
        const double PI = 3.14159256;
        double shag = 0.1;
        double mashtab = 30;

        int fillHeight = 150;
        int fillWight = 500;
        int otstup = 0;

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Pen pe = new Pen(Color.Red);

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(4*PI/shag);

        Point[] pointSin = new Point[n];

        int p = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        for(double i = 0; i < 4 * PI; i += shag)
        {
            pointSin[p] = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(i*mashtab+otstup), 
            Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sin(i)*mashtab+(fillHeight / 2) + otstup));
            p++;
        }
        g.DrawCurve(pe, pointSin);
        g.DrawLine(pen, 250, 0, 250, 500);
        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 250, 500, 250);
    }
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graphics();
    }
}
}
````

помогити...
заранее спасибо)

Comment: Напишите, хотя бы, что за ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приветствую **Alexey Kosarev**.
Субъективно конечно, но для начала - когда вылетает та или иная ошибка, попробуй её загуглить. 
Если не удалось, то обращайся на форумы или специализированные сайты, но обязательно указывайте:

- Код, который вызывает ошибку.
- Строку.
- Полный текст ошибки.

Скопировал Ваш код и проверил, у меня выбило ошибку:

- -Индекс находился вне границ массива.

Обращу внимание, что при вводе `p = 5`, то  во время работы Вашего цикла, происходит реально выход за границы массива. Массив имеет `126 элементов`, а `p = 130`.

Решение, возможно не верное(добавил в цикл проверку на выход за границы массива).

```
 void graphics()
    {
        const double PI = 3.14159256;
        double shag = 0.1;
        double mashtab = 30;

        int fillHeight = 150;
        int fillWight = 500;
        int otstup = 0;

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        Pen pe = new Pen(Color.Red);

        int n = Convert.ToInt32(4 * PI / shag);
        double test = 4 * PI;
        Point[] pointSin = new Point[n];
        int p = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        for (double i = 0; i <= 4 * PI && p < n; i += shag) // добавляем проверку, не выходит ли наш индекс за границы массива. 
        {
            pointSin[p] = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(i * mashtab + otstup),
            Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sin(i) * mashtab + (fillHeight / 2) + otstup));
            p++;
        }
        g.DrawCurve(pe, pointSin);
        g.DrawLine(pen, 250, 0, 250, 500);
        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 250, 500, 250);
    }
```

Обращу внимание, у Вас 126 элементов, при вводе `P` у Вас  `P = введеному числу`, и `P++` будет выполняться пока `i <= 4 * PI`. 
По этому у Вас `P` всегда выходил за границы массива. 
Проверка на `P < N` - не лучшее решение, но решает Вашу проблему.